# Nodes wont show up in 3D viewport

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, shaders

I am trying to toon shade my model however nothing is showing up in the 3D view port. I have done everything the videos have told me to do to start a material with shading, and it can be seen on the shading tab, however you should be able to see the shading in the 3D veiwport as well which i dont have. I also cant find the cycles option either.

How can i get the nodes to show up in the 3D viewport?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually in rendered mode; you're still in solid mode. Press Z and a pie menu will show up. Click on rendered to show all your materials.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! it worked!